# IOrderedQueryable- Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, iqueryable

I am getting a InvalidCast exception when I try to iterate through an IOrderedQueryable object as below.

appreciate any help:

```
        IOrderedQueryable<Result> rs =
                               from res in db.Results
                               orderby res.Id
                               select res;
            if (rs != null)
            {
                IEnumerator<Result> enumerator = rs.GetEnumerator();
                try
                {
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Result r = enumerator.Current;
                        Console.WriteLine(r.BugId);
                    }
                }
             }
```

Run-time error:

```
 System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data
 StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at Read_Result(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: At what line do you get this error?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use a `foreach` instead of `IEnumerator`?

Comment: I see no explicit casts. Is this really a run-time exception (and not a compile-time error)?

Comment: i see same error with foreach.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question. This gist represents the code above with values substituted where needed and compiles and runs w/o issue: https://gist.github.com/hempels/c7283e8d7e6d0ecbf7df

Comment: The problem is in what you left out of your question, and that makes your question unanswerable in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that inside your `Results` table you have column that is supposed to be an `Int32` on `DBContext` level but some of values that are inside it cannot be casted to `Int32`. Make sure that your `DBContext` matches table definition. Maybe you forgot to update it after some table schema changes...

Comment: updated my dbml file by deleting tables whose schema has changed. I was expecting BugId to be an int but it was a string :-) and there are rows in the table where bugId is empty or null or a number. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the `r.BugId` part.

The code of `Result` seems to indicate it is an `int`, but the returned value from the database isn't (maybe it is `null`?). Hence, you receive this error message.

Check if `BugId` is indeed an integer in the database, if not, and `Result` is generated though code, try to regenerate.